# Sign PDF on macOs using USB TOKEN support

Tags: java, digital-signature, signature

I am developing software that allows signing PDF documents using cryptographic support.

Now I can do this on windows using DSS signature, except DSS doesn't allow signing on macOS using a USB token.

Is there a solution other than DSS that I can use on macOS to resolve this blockage ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [AppleSignatureToken](https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/5.10.x/dss-token/src/main/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/token/AppleSignatureToken.java) available in DSS 5.10.

Also [Pkcs11SignatureToken](https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/5.10.x/dss-token/src/main/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/token/Pkcs11SignatureToken.java) should work for MacOS as well, but you need a corresponding software, reading the smartcard/USB token.

You may also try a cross-platform [mocca](https://github.com/esig/dss-demonstrations/tree/master/sscd-mocca-adapter), or create a signature with ready-to-use [Nexu](https://github.com/nowina-solutions/nexu) bundle.

Best regards,
Aleksandr.